# Adding a weighting to curve fit

Tags: python, dataframe, curve-fitting

So I have a curve fit, and I'm wondering how to include the weighting based on the standard error.

Here's the df (defined as df_altered):

```
Temperature Growth_rate Standard_Error  Result  Final_results Weight

14.0        0.363       0.110           0.000   0.363         9.091
18.0        0.677       0.043           0.767   0.673         23.256
22.0        0.822       0.044           0.975   0.832         22.727
26.0        0.936       0.073           0.975   0.920         13.699
30.0        0.897       0.051           0.767   0.911         19.608
```

And here's the curve fit setup (I don't really know if this qualifies as a curve fit, though):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = df_altered['Temperature']
y1 = df_altered['Growth_rate']
y2 = df_altered['Final_results']

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(x, y1, 'r-')
ax2.plot(x, y2, 'g-')

ax1.set_xlabel('Temperature (°C)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Observed growth rate', color='r')
ax2.set_ylabel('Optimised modelled growth rate', color='g')

plt.show()
```

So essentially, I'd like to use the Weight and Standard_Error columns as a set of parameters to determine the weighting of the plots (the smaller the standard error, the greater the weighting). I've already set this up with popt2:

```
popt2, pcov2 = curve_fit(boatman_temperature_function_optimised, xdata = df_altered.Temperature, ydata = df_altered.Growth_rate, p0 = array_of_maxima, sigma=df_altered.Weight, bounds = (array_of_minima, array_of_maxima), absolute_sigma=True)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you efit the question to put the data definition in a code block?

Comment: Done that, should look better now

Comment: What do you mean by "weighting of the plots"?

Comment: So based on the standard error, the data points will be weighted accordingly. The smaller the standard error, the greater the weighting. So I'd like to factor in the weighting and standard error for the 'Growth_rate', 'Result', and 'Final_results' variables, as opposed to simply plotting the variables. Does that make sense?

Comment: To clarify further, I set up a weight function which I'd like to factor into the plots:

def weight_function(weight, temp, standard_error):
    if standard_error > 0.00:  
        weight = 1 / standard_error
    else:
        weight = 0.00
    final = weight
    return(final)

Comment: However, I don't know if I will need to add the standard error and weight as two other axes.